# how can I select the someone names in a table whose start date and finish date difference is greater than 14

Tags: sql, oracle, select, datediff

The used query is the following:

```
select name (select(to_date(finish, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - to_date(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) diff_hours from x)
where diff_hours> 14;
```

ıt gives an error:

```
ORA-00936: missing expression : select name (select(to_date(finish, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - to_date(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) diff_hours from x) where diff_hours> 14
```

Comment: is finish and a of type char/varchar?

Comment: finish and a varchar2

Comment: And do you store time in them? If its just date where do you expect time should come from?

Comment: yes I store the date like 13.12.2014 and take the difference of them using "select(to_date(finish, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - to_date(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) diff_hours 
from x;".Now I need to reach the name that is stored in some column,if its datediff is greater than 14 days.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you missed a `from` after `name`.

```
 select name from (select(to_date(finish, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - to_date(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) diff_hours from x) where diff_hours> 14;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT name
FROM x
WHERE (TO_DATE(finish, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - TO_DATE(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) > 14;
```

Comment: unfortunately,doesnt work   ORA-00904: "DIFF_HOURS": invalid identifier : SELECT name,(TO_DATE(finish, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - TO_DATE(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy')) diff_hours FROM x WHERE diff_hours> 14

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias at the same level where it is defined.  One method is to repeat the expression, and another is to use a subquery.  When using a subquery, the subquery goes in the `from` clause:

```
select t.name, t.diff_hours
from (select name, (to_date(finish, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - to_date(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy'))*24 as diff_hours
      from x
     ) t
where diff_hours > 14;
```

In addition, the difference between two dates is the number of days.  To get the difference in hours, you need to multiply by 24.

Answer (score 0):

As it has already been said several times, you cannot use an alias in the `where` clause of the query defining it. Using a subquery to solve that issue is a common solution. An other solution is to use a CTE. For such a simple query, this is probably only a matter of taste. For more complex ones, this might help improve readability though:

```
with cte as
  (select name,
          (to_date(finish, 'dd.mm.yyyy') - to_date(a, 'dd.mm.yyyy'))*24 diff_hours
          from x
  )
select * from cte where diff_hours > 14;
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT name
FROM  `table` 
WHERE DATEDIFF( end_date, start_date )*24 >14